# Can I use blade templating engine (laravel) with symfony?

Tags: symfony, templates, laravel-5, twig, laravel-blade

I was learning symfony from it's official documentation last night and everything was working fine unless I felt the need to master twig. 
I've been working on laravel for about last 6 - 8 months and I'm really used to it's environment and the blade engine especially. The question is, can I use blade templating in symphony instead of twig ?.
I tried searching for it but couldn't find it. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: start a bounty please - i'm personally interested if this  can be done in a simple way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`composer search blade` returns:

```
philo/laravel-blade Use the simple and yet powerful Laravel Blade templating engine as a standalone component.
duncan3dc/blade Use Laravel Blade templates without the full Laravel framework
```

It looks like `philo/laravel-blade` has more maintainers, at least according to github. So, it should be possible.

Answer (score 0):

NOTE: Tested on symfony v7+ and PHP 8.1

Yes it's entirely possible to do so, I'd suggest you go with BladeOne, since it is one of the current and actively maintained

step 1: install the package with composer

```
composer require eftec/bladeone
```

step 2: create a new Service `src/Service/Helpers.php

```php
namespace App\Service;

Use eftec\bladeone\BladeOne;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;

class Helpers
{
    function __construct()
    {
        // nothing for now
    }

    function render($template, $data = [])
    {
        $views = __DIR__ . '/../../templates';
        $cache = __DIR__ . '/../../var/cache';
        $blade = new BladeOne($views, $cache, BladeOne::MODE_AUTO);
        echo $blade->run($template, $data);
    }

}
```

step 3: Register the created service

```yaml
services:
    # previous code

    App\Service\Helpers:
        autowire: true
```

step 4: use it in your controller

```php
namespace App\Controller;

use App\Service\Helpers;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;

class PublicController extends AbstractController
{
    # [Route('/', name: 'home')]
    public function index(Helpers $helpers): Response
    {
        $helpers->render('public.index', ['title' => 'Public Page']);
        return new Response();
    }
}
```

step 5: call your controller to the ur route